# Can i forrce browser to import certificate

Tags: tomcat

I Have apache tomcat 6 , i am using https SSL , currently browser is dowloading and importing certificate automatically , can i force browser to import certificate , not to get from web server

Comment: Most probably this is a browser-specific question. I think it would work very differently with Internet Explorer and Firefox. Which browser does it have to work with?

Comment: Question is very confused. "currently browser is dowloading and importing certificate automatically" - no its not. Whatever its doing its not automatically accepting CA certs or unrecognised certs automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you are asking.

You want to move the task of your web server verifying that it is who it says it is, and put that in the control of the client machine.

Does that sound sensible?

At least that's how it sounds to me.

Comment: I agree. But maybe he wants to do it for testing purposes, however I'd love to learn about THAT test goal then.

Answer (score 0):

You should only have to import the certificate once, for each browser and you are done.  You can't automatically do this because that would break the trust of SSL.  You shouldn't be changing your certs all the time.

Now what you CAN do is create your own CA, and import that CA's cert into your browser, and any cert you generated using that CA, would be trusted by the browser you imported that cert into.